# How to copy paste in sql with data and border to notepad?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, notepad

I want to copy paste my data result in `sql` to notepad including the border ( the `datagridview`)
because  i want to  see them organize but when i paste the data in notepad its a wreck or not organized

I've tried copying the result to excel and paste it again to notepad but still not working is still the same result. I Tried pasting it to microsoft word adding a border and pasting it back to notepad still not working. Do i need to create a result that will convert the text to html . Please enlighten me

```
select cast(cdvhdr.cdvdate AS varchar(12) ) as Transaction_Date
       , cdvhdr.VendorName
       , vendor.payee as Payee_Rigestered
       , cdvhdr.payee as Payee
       , cdvhdr.Cdvno as Document_Number
       , cdvhdr.trantype
       , cdvhdr.amount
       , cdvhdr.Sino as Sales_Invoice
from cdvhdr
     , vendor
where  cdvhdr.vendorname = vendor.name 
and vendor.payee != cdvhdr.payee
```

result is 13,000 data  that i need to convert into raw data with organized table (data gridview) in notepad

Comment: you can export your data to excel then you can put border

Comment: yes, But my boss want the result in notepad so im trying to find solution for this. he want to see the raw data results from the system :)

Comment: notepad is not capable of drawing any other things than plain-text. Sure, you can virtually achieve this by using "-" and "|", but this is nothing that is done automagically during a paste-operation.

Comment: sorry to say this but notepad is not made for this. you either have to use a spreadsheet like excell or export in image form. all notepad knows is chars.

Comment: so i have to organized them manually bro ?. maybe there is  a way for this

Comment: if you must use notepad, you have to "draw the lines" yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can export your data to csv file.

And select pipe delimeter. **|**

And be sure the your columns length is the same. You can set it from sql. 
   find max length and fill the columns with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can select `Results to Text` at `SQL Server Management Studio` and copy the results to notepad.

you can select this option with press `Ctrl + T` or from menu `Query -> Results To -> Results to Text`